# How to update a matrix field for an entry with craft()->db->createCommand()?

Tags: createcommand

Is it possible to update a matrix field for a know entry id and a known matrixfield id with `craft()->db->createCommand()`.

The matrixfield has 3 fields as follows:

1. time (already set - category field set as times i.e. 09:00:00)
2. session (entries field)
3. booked (lightswitch)

What I want to do is this:

UPDATE (tablename??) SET matrixfield.session = knownEntry, matrixfield.booked = 1 where matrixfieldId = knownMatrixfieldId

The reason for doing it with `craft()->db->createCommand()` is it will be fired within the `onSaveEntry` event as per my [previous post](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/16051/is-it-possible-to-update-an-entry-in-one-section-whilst-saving-data-of-an-entry)

I've done a lot of head scratching and searching on this one but I'm coming up blank.